# clientContext.load not retrieving some columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am attempting to retrieve the columns from a single item.  For whatever reason I am having troubles getting 2 columns from my list.  columns (last and next)

request failed Column 'Last' does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.  /sites/mysite/quotes/list/autoquotenumbertest.  undefined

[image]

Currently I'm just trying to alert the columns so I know they are retrieved.  But what I would really like to do is set the column Last = Next once my form is saved successfully.

What am I doing wrong?  The other columns are retrieve no problem.  Code i'm using:

```
function AutoGenerate() {
 
     var targetListItem;
     clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     web = clientContext.get_web();
     var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
     camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
     this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
     clientContext.load(listItems);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),
         Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
 }
    
 function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
     var itemId = 1;  
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
     var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AutoQuoteNumberTest');
     targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
     clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'NextQuoteNumber','Title','ID','Modified','Last','Next');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
     
 }

  function onQuerySucceeded() {
     var AutoIncremental = targetListItem.get_item('NextQuoteNumber');
     var lastnumber = targetListItem.get_item('Last');
     var nextnumber = targetListItem.get_item('Next');
  alert(AutoIncremental);
  alert(lastnumber);
  alert(nextnumber);
     $("input[title^='Quote Number']").val(AutoIncremental);
     $("input[title^='Quote Number']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
     alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

[image: mylist]

Comment: `Last` is probably not the internal name of the column. Check that and adjust your query to use the internal name instead.

Comment: Try `clientContext.load(targetListItem)` (i.e. without specifying column names manually) and see if you are getting these two columns. Also check what is the internal name of these columns.

Comment: That was exactly right.  The 'internal name' was different.  Do you have thoughts on how I would add a function to update the column last to next?  I'm not sure what the code would be do accomplish this.  I would only want to update the item on submission.

Answer (score 0):

To help you better, are you trying to make **column `Last` = column `Next`** ?

If yes, you can try to use the following code:

```
    var oListItems, clientContext;
 
function UpdateListItem() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
 
    // Specify list title here
    var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("<ListName>");
 
    // Get Item using CAML Query
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Text\'>aa</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    oListItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
 
    clientContext.load(oListItems, 'Include(Last,Next)');
 
    // Execute the query to the server.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfailed);
}
 
function onsuccess() {

    var oEnumerator = oListItems.getEnumerator();
 
    while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var NextItem = oEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Next');
        alert(NextItem);
    }

    // Get list item count of the items to be updated
    var itemCount = oListItems.get_count();
 
    for (var i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++) {
        var oListItem = oListItems.itemAt(i);
        oListItem.set_item("Last",NextItem );
        oListItem.update();
    }
 
    //Execute the batch
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(FinalQuerySuccess, FinalQueryFailure);
} 
 
function onfailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
 
function FinalQuerySuccess(sender, args) {
    console.log("success");
}
 
function FinalQueryFailure(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

My Test result:

Before:[image]After:[image]

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.